# Curvature equation

Tags: spin-geometry, gauge-theory

The curvature equation of Seiberg-Witten equations is
$F^+_A=\psi\otimes\psi^*-\frac{|\psi|^2}{2}Id$,
where $F^+_A$ is selfdual part of curvature and $\psi$ is spinor.

Could someone elaborate why could we subtract the terms and get a bound
$|F^+_A(x)|=|\psi(x)|^2/2$?